# What is the dots before Missed App Point on the Jeppesen VOR Chart?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, approach, vor, jeppesen, non-precision-approach

[image]What is the dots before Missed App Point on the Jeppesen VOR Chart ? and also why the pull up vector before the missed approach point ? Thanks.

Comment: This obviously isn't from the US with a CDFA approach.  European or Canadian?

Comment: This chart belongs to Bursa Yenisehir Airport - Turkey LTBR

Comment: Can you post this entire Instrument Approach Chart?

Answer (score 2):

The dots are a continuation of the glidepath to the runway.  This procedure is designed to follow the CDFA approach concept.  Constant Descent Final Approach.

Above the profile view is a table showing DME distances and altitudes.  You can see it in the attached image above.  The idea is to start the descent at the 9.0 DME inboard towards the VOR and to try and hit the altitudes on the table for each 1NM.  If you can do this, you will be on a constant descent to the runway which is a 3.30° glidepath.

The missed approach arrow is before the MAP because if you continue at MDA after that point, you may not be in a position to land within the touchdown zone on the runway.  This is part of the CDFA concept.

I can't tell from the attached picture above but the minimums may have (MDA) or  (DA) listed.  If it is a MDA (which it probably is) increase the altitude listed by at least 50' to make it a derived decision altitude (DDA).  This allows you to descend on a constant descent and if you don't have the airport/runway in sight at the DDA, to execute the missed approach without going below MDA.

Comment: This isn't a US chart.  However, usually on a U.S. chart, there will be a note stating "Only authorized operators may use VNAV DA(H) in lieu of MDA(H)."  That note is found in the profile view and should be seen in the attached picture but it isn't.  Until we can look at the exact plate asked about it is impossible to know for sure.

Comment: What is missing is the country this is for.  That will tell us a lot about the MDA or DA issue.  I am assuming since it is a CDFA approach, it will have DA minimums.  And since it isn't from the U.S. I doubt that note would be there.

Comment: It's likely the minimums would be listed as "DA/MDA(H)." It will be helpful if the OP posts the entire plate.